# Special case of multi variable integration with natural log result?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

We know the famous equation $PV = nRT$ but in thermodynamics we typically deal with differentials $P\,dV$ and even $V\,dP$ at times.

Given:
$$
d(PV) = V\,dP + P\,dV
$$
integrating both sides
$$
PV = \int \frac{nRT}{P}\,dP + \int \frac{nRT}{V}\,dV 
$$

Typically I'm assuming a decoupling constant can be used to decouple the factors particularly $P$ and $V$.

In fact physically the system is not defined for the first 2 variables which we can assume are independent.

So the number of moles can't change and the temperature can also be assumed independent.

After integration assuming $n$ and $T$ are independent:
$$
PV = nRT \cdot \ln(PV)
$$
Is this a special result that should be memorized in multivariable calculus regarding a natural log of the same compound variable on the left?

Comment: decoupling constant.. what is that?

Comment: the system is not defined for the first 2 variable? I believe in the ideal gas approx, PV implies the T given the moles are fixed

Comment: I don't think I understand still, could you try address my second comment?

Comment: So in this case the decoupling constant would allow me to treat the V as an independent so it's zero and then also cancel out the lnP as I have to multiply it

Answer (score 1):

$$
d(PV) = V\,dP + P\,dV
$$
integrating both sides
$$
PV = \int (\frac{nRT}{P}\,dP + \frac{nRT}{V}\,dV)
$$

If we parametrize to same variable or make V a function of P then this works but if we leave dV as dV then we can divide by dP and see

$$
\frac{d(PV)}{dP} = V + P \frac{dV}{dP}\
$$

This seems to be an issue when dP dV d.... Are not independent of each other and especially when all but one is independent variable then you can cancel all but one

I believe when the differentials dP dV dN dS are not independent they call it an inexact  differential while say dx dy dz (R3 orthogonal) is an exact differential